Tomcat fails on Debian
I have a server with Debian. I have installed in it Postgis spatial database and geoserver with tomcat9.
Sometimes the Tomcat server crashes when there are many users using it, which seems normal to me because at the moment I don't have way to improve the hardware specifications. What seems strange to me is that it collapses when no one is using it, for example, sometimes it collapses on weekends when no one is using it. What could be happening with tomcat? If someone can help me, I leave the configuration applied to the virtual machine in the file /etc/default/tomcat9
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64

JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xms6144m -Xmx6144m -Xss512k -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200 -Xloggc:/var/log/tomcat9/gc.log -XX:+UseLargePages -XX:LargePageSizeInBytes=256m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"

Server's hardware specifications are:
Processor: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2640 v2 @ 2.00GHz with 2 cores
RAM: 8 GB
Hard disk: de 500 GB
These are the lastest logs in the file /var/log/tomcat9/catalina.out
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Setting LargePageSizeInBytes has no effect on this OS. Large page size is 2048K.
[2024-08-18 12:16:45] [info] OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Failed to reserve large pages memory req_addr: 0x0000000000000000 bytes: 251658240 (errno = 12).
[2024-08-18 12:16:45] [info] OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Failed to reserve large pages memory req_addr: 0x0000000680000000 bytes: 6442450944 (errno = 12).
[2024-08-18 12:16:45] [info] OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Failed to reserve large pages memory req_addr: 0x0000000000000000 bytes: 12582912 (errno = 12).                   [2024-08-18 12:16:45] [info] OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Failed to reserve large pages memory req_addr: 0x0000000000000000 bytes: 12582912 (errno = 12).
[2024-08-18 12:16:45] [info] OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Failed to reserve large pages memory req_addr: 0x0000000000000000 bytes: 100663296 (errno = 12).
[2024-08-18 12:16:45] [info] OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Failed to reserve large pages memory req_addr: 0x0000000000000000 bytes: 100663296 (errno = 12). 


That's not normal, what do the log files show?

I have added to my question the lastest logs in the file /var/logs/tomcat9/catalina.out

I suspect that the 6Gb of memory you are requesting is more than is available - try taking the largePage stuff out and reducing the -Xmx value to 2Gb

I have removed the use of large pages and set the Xms values ​​to 1024m and Xms to 2048m. So far the server is working fine and the memory usage dropped from 80% to 50%. I left the answer too thanks for the help

After several days of operation, memory usage continues to rise even though no one is using the server, what could be happening?

Has it reached the maximum amount of memory you allocated? If not it will probably increase towards that value before clearing memory. Unless you see out of memory errors I would stop worrying about it

I have removed large Page and set the values ​​for Xms to 1024m and Xmx to 2048m as I understand this limits when the GC should clean up the memory and it is working fine so far and the logs now look like this and the memory used is reaching 50% at most.
[82630,721s][info][gc] GC(157) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 768M->134M(1024M) 13,206ms
[82919,114s][info][gc] GC(158) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 767M->128M(1024M) 10,386ms
[83207,588s][info][gc] GC(159) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 768M->128M(1024M) 10,209ms
[83495,949s][info][gc] GC(160) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 768M->128M(1024M) 11,574ms
[83778,121s][info][gc] GC(161) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 767M->130M(1024M) 10,105ms
[84066,603s][info][gc] GC(162) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 768M->129M(1024M) 9,497ms
[84355,037s][info][gc] GC(163) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 768M->128M(1024M) 9,700ms
[84643,631s][info][gc] GC(164) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 768M->134M(1024M) 12,717ms
[84926,065s][info][gc] GC(165) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 768M->134M(1024M) 10,205ms
[85217,191s][info][gc] GC(166) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 767M->128M(1024M) 11,814ms
[85499,680s][info][gc] GC(167) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 768M->133M(1024M) 11,689ms

I leave the complete configuration done in the JVM in the file /etc/default/tomcat9
JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m -Xss512k -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200 -Xloggc:/var/log/tomcat9/gc.log -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"

